# LARAVEL - Unable to create configured logger

Tags: laravel

my config/logging.php file looks like below

```
 <?php

   use App\Services\Logging\MongoLogger;

  return [

  'default' => env('LOG_CHANNEL', 'stack'),

'channels' => [
    'stack' => [
        'driver' => 'stack',
        'channels' => ['daily'],
    ],
    'logins' => [
        'driver' => 'custom',
        'via' => MongoLogger::class,
        'name' => 'login',
        'database' =>  'logs',
        'collection' => 'login_logs',
    ],

    
],
```

];

I am calling it like below

```
Log::channel('logins')->info('LOGIN_FAILED', $this->body);
```

I am getting below error

```
Unable to create configured logger. Using emergency logger. {"exception":"[object] (InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): Log [logins] is not defined. at /src/vendor/illuminate/log/LogManager.php:192)
```

Update Config file

Comment: Can you please show your full logging configuration

Comment: @parth added my logging.php file

Comment: are you using the package `jiannei/laravel-logger` ?

Comment: @N69S no i am using Monolog and mongodb/mongodb

Comment: May https://github.com/spresnac/logcrawler-client and https://github.com/spresnac/logcrawler2-server can inspire you how to log your logs to somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old question, but it hasn't any answer.

We don't see your App\Services\Logging\MongoLogger file. I have this error too and it comes from there. This file should look like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Services\Logging;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Monolog\Handler\AbstractProcessingHandler;
use Monolog\Logger;

class MongoLogger extends AbstractProcessingHandler
{
    /**
     * Create a custom Monolog instance.
     */
    public function __invoke(array $config): Logger
    {

        // Create a Monolog instance with a custom database handler
        $logger = new Logger('logins');

        // Add the current MongoLogger as a handler to itself
        $logger->pushHandler($this);

        return $logger;
    }

    /**
     * Store the log data in the database
     *
     * @param array $record
     * @return void
     */
    protected function write(array $record): void
    {
        DB::table('logs')->insert([
            'data' => json_encode($record),
            'url' => request()->fullUrl(),
            'user_id' => auth()->id()
        ]);
    }
}
```

Use you DB table and columns accordingly. Also you ca omit these rows in config/logging:

```
  // 'name' => 'login',
  // 'database' =>  'logs',
  // 'collection' => 'login_logs',
```